# Windows dialog default heading

Tags: wpf, dialog

Is there a built-in default Style or WPF element that would give me the equivalent styled text "Choose a connection option" below?

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511327.TopRules07(en-us,MSDN.10).png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511327.TopRules07(en-us,MSDN.10).png)

I'm thinking that this Heading would change to match the OS (XP, Vista, 7) that the app is running in.

Comment: I can't edit yet (lacking reputation points) - but connection is spelled incorrectly in the question

Answer (score 1):

It's "Main Instruction" text, which is

> 12 pt. blue (#003399) Segoe UI

according to the [Vista UX Guidelines for text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974176.aspx)

Comment: So WPF does not offer a built-in CustomControl/Label/etc that I could use?  I'd like the app to change based on the user's system prefs, rather than defining my own MainInstruction custom control.  Is the "12 pt. blue (#003399) Segoe UI" already defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Not in WPF, no.

You can use GetThemeFont and GetThemeColor from the Win32 visual styles APIs, but only when visual styles are enabled. Visual styles are disabled in classic themes (Windows Classic and the high contrast themes), so you'll need to hard-code alternatives for such cases. Look up AeroStyle.xml in the Windows SDK to see what the classic fall-back values are.

I've written more about this here: http://blog.quppa.net/2011/04/30/windows-theme-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to consult the Vista UX Guidelines, which outlines things like that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Read this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

It has everything you want to know about changing the window's frame, look at the "**Extending the glass frame**" and "**Removing redundant information from the title bar**" sections.